# Difference between the 2 queries

Tags: sql, oracle

Do you know what's the practical difference in the select part of these two queries?

Query1:

```
SELECT Table1.column1, Table1.column2, COUNT(DISTINCT(Table1.column1 || '|' || Table1.column2))
FROM Table1
WHERE... 
GROUP BY table1. Column1, table1. Column2
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Table1.column1, Table1.column2, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
WHERE...
GROUP BY table1. Column1, table1. Column2
```

Comment: They count different things.  What are you really trying to ask?

Comment: Thanks, because it seems they are counting the same things.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is more efficient.

Comment: So it's just a performance difference? The result of the query should be the same?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it is an operator. No need for brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are very different.

The second query will return the number of rows in each group.

The first query will return 1 for each group, because you are counting DISTINCT values, and within a group, the expression you are counting is constant.

What is your example that shows that the two queries return the same result? It must not have duplicates by (column1, column2); if it did, you would see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain better this part "...because you are counting DISTINCT values, and within a group, the expression you are counting is constant."?

Comment: @John -  When you group by the two columns, you will get several groups, and each group will have one or more rows. Within each group, considered in isolation (just the rows in that group), all the rows have the same value in column1, and the same value in column2 (same in all the rows, that is; it may still be different from the value in column1). That is the very definition of GROUP BY. So, then, column1 || ‘|’ || column2 is the same for all rows in a group. And count distinct is within each group. In each group, there is only one distinct value for that expression.

Answer (score -1):

You will have differerent answers for the queries:

1. Return the number of distincts combinations
   More informations here https://community.oracle.com/ideas/18664
2. Return the total number of rows with the same informations

Comment: Wrong answer. The count is not of any arbitrary column, it is for a very specific expression.